# Android studio 3.5: NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.5

### After updated Android studio from 3.4.2 to 3.5 I see the following warning message on the Build log messages.

> NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1,
>       NDK version is UNKNOWN

I am using the following installed

```
Build-tools: 29.0.2 

NDK side by side: 20.0.5594570  

NDK: 20.0.5594570
```

I have the following in by `build.gradle`

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

> **Note:** Even though I am receiving this warning message, the build got succeeded without any problem so this is not a blocking issue. Anyway I want to get rid of this warning.

**I have seen the following threads but it does not help**

**1. Suggestion 1:** suggests to opening project using Import project (Gradle, Eclipse, etc.)

*Comment:* I reimported the project via the said option, but did not help. Also tried deleting build folders, restart-invalidate caches etc.

*Result:* The warning message still persists

**2. Suggestion 2:** You just need to open local.properties & change ndk.dir path to your NDK path.

*Comment:* I already have the following on my `local.properties`

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

*Result:* The warning message still persists

**3. Suggestion 3:** Go to your build.gardle(Project) and then change the classpath of gardle to 3.5.0 after Sync project android studio will use gradle-5.4.1

*Comment:* I already have this configuration on my `build.gradle`

*Result:* The warning message still persists

**4. Suggestion 4:** As suggested by one of the answer below, download the SDK from the given link and setup it in a separate folder.

*comment:* I did as suggested.

*Result:* The warning message still persists

After trying all of the above suggestions that I found on different threads/comments/answers, nothing seems working.

Answer (score -1):

Download a separate NDK, e.g. https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r20-windows-x86_64.zip

Then unzip it to a directory, e.g.`C\:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\ndk`, and point your `ndk.dir` to it. i.e.

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\ndk\\android-ndk-r20-windows-x86_64
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

Or, copy the whole content of the newly downloaded NDK and **overwrite the content inside** `ndk-bundle` directory

**Edit #1**

Or try to **import** the project rather than directly open it, see below:

[image]

Comment: I already have up to date NDK under my android SDK folder, do i need to download again?

Comment: I doubt your NDK inside ndk-bundle may miss something and your AS could not recognise it properly. Downloading a separate one and manually point to it may fix your problem.

Comment: I downloaded the SDK and setup as suggested, but the warning message still persists.

Comment: Try to import the project as said in my updates

Comment: tried, no luck. warning message persists after sync.