# Can I set the ndk.dir out of the sdk.dir path, why there is no ndk.dir automatic creation?

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I fetch a project from Windows to my local Mac environment.

You see there, under the `Gradle Script`, the `local.properties`:

```
ndk.dir=D\:\\sdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=/Users/lisa/software/android-sdk-macosx
```

you see there has the `ndk.dir` and `sdk.dir`, the latter is my new Mac SDK path, but the `ndk.dir` did not change now. from the `D\:\\sdk\\ndk-bundle`, whether we know the `ndk-bundle` should be under the sdk path(`/Users/lisa/software/android-sdk-macosx`)?

[image]

but in the `/Users/lisa/software/android-sdk-macosx`, there is no that directory:

```
lisa-MacBook-Pro:android-sdk-macosx ldl$ pwd
/Users/lisa/software/android-sdk-macosx
lisa-MacBook-Pro:android-sdk-macosx ldl$ ls
SDK Readme.txt  build-tools platforms   sources     temp
add-ons     platform-tools  skins       system-images   tools
```

Whether I should create the `/Users/lisa/software/android-sdk-macosx/ndk-bundle`? and set ndk.dir?

can I set the ndk.dir anywhere, such as out the `sdk.dir` path?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57706250/8034839 if it helps

Comment: Yes, you can put NDK anywhere, but if you let the SDK Manager install NDK for you, it may be easier to maintain. The file `local.properties` is not expected to be copied from one computer to another.

Answer (score 1):

As of gradle plugin 3.5, the behavior is closer to what you're describing: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk

`ndk.dir` is deprecated, and the NDK will normally come from the SDK directory. You can select the exact version you want with the `android.ndkVersion` gradle property, or it will select a default. If you specify `ndk.dir` I believe that will override, but that is the obsolete workflow.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem disabling NDK Support in Settings>Plugins>Android NDK support.

[image]